# what is the efficient way to update existing child and append new child object to parent in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

What is the efficient way to update existing child model and add new child model to parent model also remove child model?

I just

```
child_inputs = [{'child_id':1, 'name': 'test1'},{'name': 'test2'}]
parent = Parent.query.get(id)

// remove child model if not exists in child_inputs like child_id 2 appended to Parent model

for inputs in child_inputs:
    if 'child_id' in inputs:
        child = Child.query.get(inputs['child_id'])
        child.name = inputs['name']
    else:
        child = Child(**inputs)
    
    parent.append(child)

db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation of the [Merging](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html#merging) usage is exactly what you need.

You need to make sure that the 'child_id' is actually the name of the primary key field, or just rename the key before processing through the `merge`.